# Random numbers based on a probability

Tags: c++, random, distribution, probability

I'm having trouble generating random numbers that do not follow a discrete uniform distribution.

So for example, say I have 5 numbers (to keep it simple), a probability of number k being generated would be k/15. (k = 1 to 5)

My idea is to generate a random number j using rand(), and if this number j is:

1 => then number 1 is generated

2 or 3 => num 2

4 or 5 or 6 => num 3

7 or 8 or 9 or 10 => num 4

11 or 12 or 13 or 14 or 15 => num 5

Now scale this to generating 1-10, 1-100, 1-1000. Does this work the way I intend it to? I've constructed a loop that pretty much does this every time a number needs to be generated, I think it's probably inefficient since it goes up until it finds the j number generated in one of the ranges... What could be a better way to do this?

EDIT: or maybe create an array once with the proper numbers and then pull out with rand() better solution?

Comment: there are many similar questions on SO.....

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/discrete_distribution/discrete_distribution/

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432226/how-do-i-select-a-range-of-values-in-a-switch-statement

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider that the sum `s` of integers from 1 to `n` is `s = n * (n + 1) / 2`.  Solve for `n` to get `n = (± sqrt(8*s + 1) - 1) / 2`.  We can ignore the negative square root, as we know `n` is positive.  Thus `n = (sqrt(8*s + 1) - 1) / 2`.

So, plugging in integers for `s` between 1 and 15:

```
s  n
01 1.000000
02 1.561553
03 2.000000
04 2.372281
05 2.701562
06 3.000000
07 3.274917
08 3.531129
09 3.772002
10 4.000000
11 4.216991
12 4.424429
13 4.623475
14 4.815073
15 5.000000
```

If we take the ceiling of each computed `n` (the smallest integer not less than `n`), we get this:

```
s  n
01 1
02 2
03 2
04 3
05 3
06 3
07 4
08 4
09 4
10 4
11 5
12 5
13 5
14 5
15 5
```

Thus you can go from the uniform distribution to your distribution in constant space and constant time (no iteration and no precomputed tables):

```
double my_distribution_from_uniform_distribution(double s) {
    return ceil((sqrt(8*s + 1) - 1) / 2);
}
```

N.B. This relies on `sqrt` giving an exact result for a perfect square (e.g. returning exactly 7 given exactly 49).  This is normally a safe assumption, because IEEE 754 requires exact rounding of square roots.

IEEE 754 doubles can represent all integers from 1 through 2^53 (and many larger integers, but not contiguously after 2^53).  So this function should work correctly for all `s` from 1 to `floor((2^53 - 1) / 8) = 1125899906842623`.

Answer (score 14):

You seem to be on the right track, but C++ already has a specialized random number distribution for that, `std::discrete_distribution`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    // list of probabilities    
    std::vector<double> p = {0, 1.0/15, 2.0/15, 3.0/15, 4.0/15, 5.0/15};
    // could also be min, max, and a generating function (n/15 in your case?)
    std::discrete_distribution<> d(p.begin(), p.end());

    // some statistics
    std::map<int, int> m;
    for(int n=0; n<10000; ++n) {
        ++m[d(gen)];
    }
    for(auto p : m) {
        std::cout << p.first << " generated " << p.second << " times\n";
    }
}
```

online demo: http://ideone.com/jU1ll

Comment: The other answers assume the intended distribution follows along with the sequence of triangular numbers but the question also refers to ranges from 1-100 and 1-1000, neither of which are triangular. So the general answer does appear to be more appropriate.

Comment: @shawnt00 The other answers make no such assumption about the range of outputs; to output a number in the range $1$ to $100,$ they would use the $100$th triangular number. However, for a fixed distribution that would be used many times, a method like this answer might still be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the curious arithmetical fact that:

```
S(n) = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (n - 1) + n
```

or simplified:

```
S(n) = n * (n + 1) / 2
```

This lets you avoid storing the array.