# c++ cannot appear in a constant-expression|

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I select a range of values in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432226/how-do-i-select-a-range-of-values-in-a-switch-statement)

I've been getting some errors, and I've been searching for some time now, but I have no idea what is the cause of the errors. (I'm quite new to programming.)

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
error: 'Essais' cannot appear in a constant-expression| (line 200)
warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion| (line 202)
```

I have case and cote:

```
  char AfficherCote (int Essais)
 {
 char Cote;
 switch (Essais)
  {
(line200)       case Essais<=20:
    {
(line 202)           Cote='Excellent';

        return (Cote);
        break;
    }
    case Essais<=40:
    {
        Cote='Très bon';
        return (Cote);
        break;
    }
    case Essais<=60:
    {
        Cote='Bon';
        return (Cote);
        break;
    }
    case Essais<=80:
    {
        Cote='Moyen';
        return (Cote);
        break;
    }
    case Essais<=100:
    {
        Cote='Muvais';
        return (Cote);
        break;
    }
    case Essais>=100:
    {
        Cote='Très mauvais';
        return (Cote);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a book? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`switch-case` only works with constant values<sup>(*)</sup> (such as `3` or `'a'`), not with ranges (such as `<=100`). You also must not include the variable name in the `case` statement. Correct syntax would be as follows:

```
switch (Essais)
{
case 1:
   /* ... */
  break;
case 2:
   /* ... */
   break;
default:
   /* ... */
}
```

If you need range tests, use `if` instead of `switch-case`:

```
if (Essais <= 80)
  return "Cote";
else if (Essais <= 100)
  return "Muvais";
```

Also note that you can't use single quotation marks `'` for strings. Use double quotation marks `"` instead, and use variables of type `std::string` (not `char`) to store strings.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> To be precise, the condition given in the `case` statements must be a *constant expression* of integral type, enumeration type, or class type *convertible* to integer or enumeration type (see §6.4.2/2 of the C++ Standard for details).

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `switch` blocks work.  You would need to do something like this instead:

```
switch (Essais) {
    case 20:
        ...
    case 40:
        ...
    case 60:
        ...
    /* etc, etc */
}
```

Each `case` compares the value in the `switch` statement against a specific constant value.  If they are equal, that block is executed.  In your code, the compiler is complaining because an expression like `Essais<=20` is not a constant that it can evaluate at compile time.

Given what you are trying to do, an `if ... else if ... else` chain would be more appropriate.  `switch` blocks can only test against specific values and can't handle testing ranges, which is what it appears you are trying to do.