# Making a random number rarity system and it's not working

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I select a range of values in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432226/how-do-i-select-a-range-of-values-in-a-switch-statement)
>   [c++ cannot appear in a constant-expression|](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354644/c-cannot-appear-in-a-constant-expression)

What I'm trying to do is generate a random number, and, depending on the value of the number, write out "Common", "Rare", or "Very Rare". Can somebody help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    srand(time(0));
    a = 1 + (rand()%10);

    switch (a)
    {
        case (a >= 0 && a <= 5):
        cout << "Common";
            break;

        case (a >= 6 && a <= 8):
        cout << "Rare";
            break;

        case (a >= 9 && a <= 10):
        cout << "Very rare";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's not working?  are you getting compilation errors? segmentation faults? do you get the same value every time? what?

Comment: -1, the title of this question doesn't describe the actual problem, and the compiler error isn't mentioned at all.

Comment: `case (a >= 0 && a <= 5):` -> How can `a` ever be 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use comparison operators in a switch case.  Try this:

```
 switch (a)
    {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        cout << "Common";
            break;

        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        cout << "Rare";
            break;

        case 9:
        case 10:
        cout << "Very rare";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Also, the switch statement ends with a semicolon.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a Java guy, so I'll believe it, but I didn't think so.

Comment: It's a = 1 + (rand()%10); So it'll add 1, making the possible range be 1-10. And yeah, I figured that was the error. Thank you very much, I didn't know I could make more than one case have the same output in  that way. Thanks again! :D

Comment: @Josué Molina: Not necessarily. In C++, classes require semicolons, switch statements don't.

Comment: Alternately, the original question could have gone with chained else-if's.

Comment: Wow, I just tested it and it works; switch statements can end and not end with a semicolon. o.o I guess we learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check ranges I recommend you to use the if statement to avoid using a list of all possible values:

```
if (a >= 0 && a <= 5)
    cout << "Common";
else if (a >= 6 && a <= 8)
    cout << "Rare";
else if (a >= 9 && a <= 10)
    cout << "Very rare";
```

Comment: Ahh yeah, that would have worked too, thanks!