# const static auto lambda used with capture by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, reference

While using some local lambda objects in a C++11 function I was tempted to declare them as `const static auto lambda = ...` just to let the compiler know that there is just one `std::function` object needed (and possibly optimize the call and/or inline it) but I realized that capturing local values by reference in this circumstance leads to weird behavior.

Consider the following code:

```
void process(const Data& data, const std::function<void(DataElement&>& lambda) {
  ...
}

void SomeClass::doSomething()
{
  int foo = 0;

  const static auto lambda = [&foo] () { .... ++foo; .... }

  process(data, lambda);
}
```

This doesn't work with multiple invocations of `doSomething()` but the mechanics is not clear.

- Is `foo` bound at the first invocation and then kept bound to a stack address which becomes invalid on successive invocations?
- Am I forced so drop `static` in this circumstance?

Where is this behavior specified in the standard? Considering it's a `static` variable where is it constructed? Lazily on first invocation of `doSomething()` (so that the first invocation works) or at program start?

Comment: Anyway, currently, you construct the `std::function` from the lambda at each call. (and the creation of your lambda is light).

Comment: Why not `static int foo = 0;` ? Since there's only one lambda bound to `foo`, you probably don't need multiple copies of `foo` either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A static function-scope variable is initialised "lazily," when control flow first reaches its declaration. This means that the capture by reference does indeed bind to the `foo` currently on stack, and when the call terminates, that binding becomes dangling.

Don't try to help the compiler too much; making `lambda` `static` looks like a micro-optimisation, with very bad side effects. There's next to no overhead involved in actually creating a closure object, and the compiler can easily inline it regardless of whether it's `static` or not.

Not to mention the fact that you're not saving on creating the `std::function` object even with your approach. The type of a lambda expression is an unnamed closure object, *not* `std::function`. So even if `lambda` is `static`, the `std::function` object is created in each call anyway (unless the whole thing is inlined).

Comment: Very interesting, especially the last  part. Could you elaborate on why the `std::function` object has to be created on each call? I don't understand why that happens...

Comment: @JorenHeit Because it's not cached anywhere. The static variable "caches" the closure object (the lambda function), but not a `std::function`. A temporary `std::function` is created by the call `process(data, lambda)` to initialise the function's parameter `lambda`.

Comment: Right... so would that be resolved if it's declared as a `std::function` rather than using auto?

Comment: @JorenHeit It would resolve the caching/re-creation, but you'd still be facing the problem with the reference to `foo` becoming dangling after the first call.

Comment: Yes, unless you make that a static as well, and make sure the body of the lambda resets it to 0 every time it's called, right?

Comment: @JorenHeit That would be one way of solving this, true. But we're getting into hack territory, for uncertain performance benefits. Is `doSomething` called so many times that the creation is a performance bottleneck? And if so, wouldn't it be better to turn `process` into a template and get rid of `std::function` altogether?

Comment: @Agnew Oh I completely agree that by now we're overcomplicating the problem immensely and it should be obvious that `static` is not the way to go. I just wanted to understand what you meant, and I do now ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> This doesn't work with multiple invocations of `doSomething()` but the mechanics is not clear.

This is because `foo` is allocated on the stack. The exact address of `foo` depends on the call stack that led to the invocation of `doSomething`. In other words, the address of `foo` is likely to be different between function invocations, unless the call stack is exactly the same.