# How to write switch statement with evalutions other than "equal to"

Tags: c++, vba, select, arduino, switch-statement

I'm trying to program an Arduino.....
In VBA (Visual Basic for Applications), one can write:

```
Select Case Range("B5").Value
    Case Is > 1000
        Dim DrawDownVolume As Integer
        DrawDownVolume = 275 + DrugVolume - 315
        Range("E14") = "PHARMACIST:   Draw out " & DrawDownVolume & " mL from 250 mL bag before adding elotuzumab."
        Range("B6").Value = 315
    Case Is < 1000
        'Continue as normal - see below
        Range("E14") = ""
        Range("B6").Value = 275 + DrugVolume
   Case Else
        'Do nothing
End Select
```

But I see no way of doing this in C++.  Can someone point out how this is done?  Basically I want to pass a variable through an evaluation event  (<, >, !=, etc) with a constant or another variable:

Case Is > TimeStamp

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  On-line, I only see switch statements and no select statements talked about.

Comment: Take a look at the C++ control structures

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select a range of values in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432226/how-do-i-select-a-range-of-values-in-a-switch-statement)

Comment: If you need to program in C++, then I suggest you learn it properly. Please get [a decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) or two.

Comment: The easiest way of doing what you are looking for is probably through a `if` statement

Comment: If you want to program in C++ then learn C++.

Answer (score 0):

Using `switch case` is not a good choice for testing ranges. The best option is to use several `if-else if` conditions as stated:

```
if (value == 0)
    // ...
else if (value < 10)
    // ...
else if (value < 25)
    // ...
else if (value < 50)
    // ...
else if (value < 100)
    // ...
else if (value >= 100)
    // ...
else
    std::cout << "ERROR!";
```

C++ has no `Is` stuff like VB.Net that could be used in `switch` statements. Although, still you can do it in a less-readable style:

```
switch (value) {
    case 0: std::cout << "0";
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3: std::cout << "Till some more ranges...";
    ...
    default: std::cout << "ERROR!";
}
```

Which will make your code super lengthy in case you use it to test lengths on `switch` statement.