# static variable inside member function of base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

i have the following:

```
   class base
   {
      public
       void f();
       ...
   }
    void base::f()
    {
        static bool indicator=false;
         .....
         if(!indicator)
         {
            ...
            indicator=true;
          }
     }
    class D:public base
    {      
       ...
     }
```

in my main() i have:

```
      main()
      {
          // first instance of D
          base *d1 = new D();
          d1->f();
           ....
           // 2nd instance of D
          base *d2 = new D();
          d2->f();
       }
```

i find that the first time i instantiate D and call d1->f() the static variable is set to false. but the 2nd time i call d2->f() the code does not even hit the line "static bool indicator=false;" and it is kept at true (from the first pass of d1-f()) This is exactly the behavior i want but i do not understand why this is happening. can someone please explain what is happening. thanks in advance

Comment: By design, the initializer is run only once for static variables within a function. If you didn't want that behavior, then you would just declare the variable as non-static. The point is to maintain the value through multiple calls of the function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Static variables declared in member functions will *keep their value between function calls*. There will be only *one copy over all instances*, and all accesses to `indicator` from different instances will affect the same `indicator`. This means `indicator` *will only be initialized once*.

See here for more info: [Static variables in member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6223355/873025)

Also this code does not toggle `indicator`, it always sets it to true if it's false (which I'm sure is the behaviour you want).

```
if(!indicator)
     {
        ...
        indicator=true;
      }
```

Comment: not your fault, but the title of the question you link is a bit confusing, because "class methods" can be understood as refering to static methods.

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, agreed. The correct C++ term would be "member functions". I've updated the title in the referenced question.

Answer (score 3):

This is precisely the behavior of static variables declared inside function blocks. It has been like that since the introduction of the feature in the C programming language.

> The static declaration can also be applied to internal variables. Internal static variables are local to a particular function just as automatic variables are, but unlike automatics, they remain in existence rather than coming and going each time the function is activated. (K&R, page 61).

The static initializer is executed before the first invocation of the containing function. Being static, the variable retains its last state across the invocations.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/35251486/3758484, this answer is incorrect as it is with regards to the C language, and this is a C++ question.

Comment: @johnbakers You are correct, compile-time constant requirement has been lifted for C++. Thanks!