# Static initializer inside member function require compile-time constant?

Tags: c++, c

I have [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15036672/3758484) it written that:

> The static initializer is executed before the first invocation of the containing function; the initializer expression must be a compile-time constant.

Consider this:

```
void func(){
   static float tr=((float) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
}
```

`tr` depends on a runtime function, `rand()`. I don't think the value of `rand()` is known at compile time, is it? Yet this compiles fine in C++ and a lot of answers/literature indicate that C behavior is the same as C++ in this regard.

Comment: C or C++? They are different languages.

Comment: @SouravGhosh on this issue, everything I have read (including the linked answer) says that the C and C++ behaviour for a static variable in a function is the same.

Comment: Just a random guess: can it be due to a strict/pedantic/so on flag not being toggled in the compiler?

Comment: @johnbakers : That is certainly not true.  This can clearly be seen by compiling your example as C and C++.

Comment: @SouravGhosh :  It is legitimate to ask a question about more than one language.  Especially when they have a common subset and common tools - then the differences between them become important to understand and it is useful to discuss them together.  However for this to compile, her is clearly using C++ because it is not valid C.

Comment: So either take out the "Yet this compiles fine." and replace it with something that correctly indicates the difference between C and C++, or take out the [tag:c] tag. Right now, this question is spreading false information.

Comment: @hvd done, thanks. indeed it was false information, learned from other false information elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++ a local static initialization is performed the first time the scope is entered and the expression doesn't need to be a constant at all. You can call any function you like. A common patter for singletons is for example:

```
MySingleton& get_instance() {
    static MySingleton s;
    return s;
}
```

where the instance will be constructed only when (and if) the `get_instance` function is called. With C++11 you're even guaranteed that there will be no problem if `get_instance` is possibly called from multiple threads at the same time as the compiler will add the needed locking logic.

In C things are different and static initialization is performed by the loader before program starts and you can only use constant expressions so the code in your question is not valid (you cannot call `rand`).

Comment: I had to repeat myself at least 3 times this:
`In C++ a local static initialization is performed the first time the scope is entered `

Nice and clear explanation, BTW

Answer (score 3):

It is valid C++, it is not valid C.

The answer linked in the question from where the quote comes from refers to the behaviour of C, but the question is clearly specific to C++.

Comment: Good to know. So then what *is* the expected behavior? The static variable depends on runtime, but is guaranteed to get initialized not at compile time, but sometime before the function is first invoked?