# Why does this static variable refuse to change?

Tags: c++, c++11, static, constants

I've been trying to write a program in C++11 for some artificial intelligence that returns a vector of objects. In order to ensure that the objects don't get deleted after the function exits, I've made them static as well as the vector. Here's the method (the other methods in the class don't matter for this, as well as the inner workings of the objects I'm placing in my vector - all that's relevant is the name of the class, `H`), as well as the testing function:

```
//hvote.h

#ifndef __HVOTE_H_INCLUDED__
#define __HVOTE_H_INCLUDED__

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include "h.h"

class Hvote
{
    public:
        Hvote();
        //This method is the class's constructor.
        //It sets both hs and alphas to empty vectors.
        //There are a bunch of instance variables and methods not shown here.
        std::vector<H>& find_hs(std::vector<std::vector<double>>&, std::vector<bool>&);
        //This method finds and returns the heuristics needed for the boosting algorithm.
};

#endif

//hvote.cpp

Hvote::Hvote()
{
    //some code to initialize the instance variables.
}

//some other methods.

std::vector<H>& Hvote::find_hs(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& points,
                               std::vector<bool>& answers)
{
    static std::vector<H> available_hs;
    int axes = points[0].size();
    for (int axis = 0; axis < axes; axis = axis + 1)
    {
        std::sort(points.begin(),
                  points.end(),
                  [=](std::vector<double> a, std::vector<double> b) mutable -> bool
                      {
                          return (a[axis] < b[axis]);
                      }
                 );
        double previous = points[0][axis];
        for (int datapoint = 0; datapoint < points.size() - 1; datapoint = datapoint + 1)
        {
            double next = points[datapoint + 1][axis];
            if (next != previous)
            {
                if (answers[datapoint + 1] != answers[datapoint])
                {
                    static H next_positive(axis, (next + previous)/2, true);
                    static H next_negative(axis, (next + previous)/2, false);
                    available_hs.push_back(next_positive);
                    available_hs.push_back(next_negative);
                }
            }
            previous = next;
        }
    }
    static std::vector<H>& available_hs_ref = available_hs;
    return available_hs_ref;
}

//main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "h.h"
#include "hvote.h"

int main()
{
    Hvote hvote;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> points;
    std::vector<bool> answers;
    for (double x = 1.0; x < 21.0; x = x + 1.0)
    {
        for (double y = 1.0; y < 21.0; y = y + 1.0)
        {
            std::vector<double> point{x, y};
            points.push_back(point);
            bool answer = (x < y);
            answers.push_back(answer);
        }
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<double>>& points_ref = points;
    std::vector<bool>& answers_ref = answers;
    std::vector<H>& hs = hvote.find_hs(points_ref, answers_ref);
    for (int i = 0; i < hs.size(); i = i + 1)
    {
        int axis = hs[i].get_axis();
        double cutoff = hs[i].get_cutoff();
        bool direction = hs[i].get_direction();
        std::cout << "Heuristic(axis = " << axis << ", cutoff = " << cutoff << ", direction = " << direction << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting a variety of `H` objects to appear on the output, with different axes, cutoffs, and directions, but to my surprise only two distinct instances of the `H` class (and a lot of duplicates of those two) appear in `hs`! Here's the output:

```
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 1)
Heuristic(axis = 0, cutoff = 1.5, direction = 0)
```

I checked that `axis`, `next`, `previous`, etc. variables do change throughout the course of the program by printing their values. I finally came to the conclusion that `next_positive` and `next_negative` just aren't changing. Why? Why do these variables refuse to change? [So far as I understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223355/static-variables-in-class-methods) (second answer), making a variable `static` just tells the compiler to leave it alone for the duration of its use (don't delete it after the method exits if it was returned and other methods will need to use it). Does `static` somehow imply `const`? What's the deal here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a variable to be static (and initialize it), it will only initialize itself **once**. Next time the variable is encountered, it's not re-initialized with a new value -- you need to assign to it.

Actually, there's really no reason at all for you to be using static vectors here if they need to be re-initialized every time the function runs. If you were attempting to perform some kind of optimization, then this optimization was premature.

In the meantime, replace:

```
  if (answers[datapoint + 1] != answers[datapoint])
  {
     static H next_positive(axis, (next + previous)/2, true);
     static H next_negative(axis, (next + previous)/2, false);
     available_hs.push_back(next_positive);
     available_hs.push_back(next_negative);
  }
```

with

```
  if (answers[datapoint + 1] != answers[datapoint])
  {
     available_hs.emplace_back(axis, (next + previous)/2, true);
     available_hs.emplace_back(axis, (next + previous)/2, false);
  }
```

So that you can at least take advantage of `emplace back`

`available_hs` should not be `static`, and the weird thing you're doing with a reference to it should also not happen; just return a `std::vector`

You should `return available_hs;`