# Cast from pointer to reference

Tags: c++, templates, static-cast

I have a generic Singleton class that I'll use for many singleton classes. The generic class is giving a compile error when converting from a pointer to reference.

> Error 3   error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'IApp *' to 'IApp &'

Below is the generic class and the compiler error occurs in the `instance()` function.

```
template<typename DERIVED>
class Singleton
{
public:

    static DERIVED& instance()
    {
        if (!_instance) {
            _instance = new DERIVED;
            std::atexit(_singleton_deleter); // Destruction of instance registered at runtime exit (No leak).
        }

        return static_cast<DERIVED&>(_instance);
    }

protected:

    Singleton() {}
    virtual ~Singleton() {}

private:

    static DERIVED* _instance;

    static void _singleton_deleter() { delete _instance; } //Function that manages the destruction of the instance at the end of the execution.

};
```

Is it possible to cast this way? I don't want `instance()` to return a pointer, I'd prefer a reference. Or maybe a `weak_ptr`? Any ideas how to cast this?

Comment: I would not use a pointer for a singleton. This implementation is not thread safe way too complicated for what you want to achieve.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Thanks for your comment. What would be more thread safe? Dependency injection?

Comment: Well... Of course dependency injection is the choice, but when you have to do with singletons, a static local variable is really the best.

Comment: Here an explanation of this particular use of the static keyword: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6223355/2104697 the only difference in your case is that you want to return a reference to the static variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is *dereferencing* of a pointer, using the indirection operator `*`. You want either

```
return static_cast<DERIVED&>(*_instance);
//                         ^^^^^
```

or

```
return *static_cast<DERIVED*>(_instance);
//   ^^^^^
```

or simply:

```
return *_instance;
//   ^^^^^
```

since `_instance` *already* has type `Derived *` and the two casts above are no-ops.